# Saving a copy of a sheet to a specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script

On the trigger of a form submission, I have created a copy of a sheet. I can't figure out how to save that copied sheet in a specific folder. Once the copy is created, I've tried calling the folder then saving the copied sheet to that folder.

```
//Copying the sheet (triggered by a form submission)

var copyOfSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Id.of.sheet.I.am.copying).copy(name of sheet);

//Grabbing the folder I want to save to

var specificFolder = Drive.App.getFolderById(folderID.in.quotes);

//saving the copy to that folder (This is the part that I think is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix)

specificFolder.addFile(copyOfSheet);
```

The goal is that the file would save in this specific folder instead of my general drive. Instead I am getting a not a function error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy a Spreadsheet and move it to the specific folder using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script was modified.

#### Modified script:

```
//Copying the sheet (triggered by a form submission)
var copyOfSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Id.of.sheet.I.am.copying).copy(name of sheet).getId();
//Grabbing the folder I want to save to
var specificFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID.in.quotes);

//saving the copy to that folder
// Retrieve the copied file.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyOfSheet);
// Add the file to "specificFolder".
specificFolder.addFile(file);
// Remove the parent folder of copied file.
file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
```

- At Google Drive, each file can have multiple parent folders. So in your case, new parent folder is added to the copied folder and a parent folder (in this case, it's root folder) is removed from the copied file.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the Spreadsheet is directly copied to the specific folder using `makeCopy()`.

#### Script:

```
var specificFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID.in.quotes);
DriveApp.getFileById(Id.of.sheet.I.am.copying).makeCopy(name of sheet, specificFolder);
```

### Note:

- These patterns supposes that the values of `Id.of.sheet.I.am.copying`, `name of sheet` and `folderID.in.quotes` are correct.

### References:

- [removeFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removefilechild)
- [addFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File))
- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Pattern 1 worked exactly like I hoped. Thank you so much!

Comment: @alpal24 Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.